# Laravel 5.5 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?'

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, composer

Creando un proyecto de Laravel 5.5 al abrir en el explorar mi proyecto me arroja el siguiente error.

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_PARSE)
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)
```

Ya intente con un `composer update`  pero el problema persiste.

Estoy creando el proyecto en ubuntu 16.04 y php 7.1
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Al aprecer era problema de compatibilidad, simplemente ejecute los siguiente
sudo a2dismod php7.0
sudo a2enmod hp7.1
sudo service apache2 restart

Answer (score 1):

A pesar de que estés instalando la versión 5.5 y cumplas con el requerimiento `PHP >= 7.0` necesitas instalar el proyecto corriendo una versión menor a la 7.1 ya que ese archivo está usando tipos "nulleables" que solamente están disponibles a partir de la versión 7.1 de PHP. El problema de esto parece que es con `nesbot/carbon`, el cuál usa las PEOOORES versiones de dependencia que haya visto ~ `"symfony/translation": "~2.6 || ~3.0 || ~4.0"`.

La verdad me sorprende que la documentación oficial no mencione nada de esto, pero si, instala la versión 5.5 dentro de un ambiente 7.0.* de PHP